# How to validate a valid GUID in Jmeter using groovy script?

Tags: groovy, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

This is the valid GUID  04a8b9f1-4a92-f21c-94f9-1544fa539f44 and i want to validate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the above issue.

```
String valid = "04a8b9f1-4a92-f21c-94f9-1544fa539f44";
        if (valid .matches("[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[1-5][0-9a-f]{3}-[89ab][0-9a-f]{3}-[0-9a-f]{12}"))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: You can just return `valid.matches()` - no need for `if (pred) { return true } else { return false }` - just `return pred`.  Also you could state the source of that regexp.

Comment: Yes, It makes more sense.

Answer (score 3):

You can validate by calling [UUID.fromString](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#fromString(java.lang.String)) method

```
UUID uuid = UUID.fromString(someUUID);
```

If UUID is invalid it will throw an exception

> Creates a UUID from the string standard representation as described in the toString() method.

Comment: Thanks. Its working, but its throwing error if it is invalid, how to manage that?

Comment: I want to restore the result(valid/invalid) in bool type variable so that i can use further. I can manage in catch block, but i dont want to manage there.

Comment: @Aditya Kumar You can set with `vars.put("isValid", "true")`

Comment: i have solved the issue. You can see my below answer.